# How to trigger a function after settimeout function which is not in our control in ES6 or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, settimeout

I need to trigger a custom JS function immediately after a function gets completed in other library Ex) CanvasJs core. As i dont have any control on canvas JS i could not able to achieve this. Please check the pseudo

```
function canvasFunction() { // I dont have any control to edit this function.
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     alert("After this call trigger my custom function."); 
   }, 3000);
}

function myCustomFunction() {
   alert("Call this once above function completes."); 
}
```

Original code:

```
$(window).on('resize.off-canvas', eventData, debounce(Drupal.offCanvas.resetSize, 100)).trigger('resize.off-canvas');

resetSize: function resetSize(event) {
  // After this function is done, i need to call my custom function.

},
```

Comment: `i could not able to achieve this` nobody can

Comment: Or unless you monkeypatch `setTimeout` or `alert` before `canvasFunction` runs (don't do that unless there's no other choice, like in a userscript)

Comment: Does the canvasFunction return anything?

Comment: Are you sure there isn’t any event hook CanvasJs offers...?

Comment: More information 

$(window).on('resize.off-canvas', eventData, debounce(Drupal.offCanvas.resetSize, 100)).trigger('resize.off-canvas');

resetSize: function resetSize(event) {
   // After this i need to call my custom function.
},

Comment: *"// After this function is done, i need to call my custom function."* Why don't you just add `myCustomFunction()` at the end of that function then?

Answer (score 2):

The original code triggers a "resize.off-canvas" event after debouncing the resetSize function for 100ms. You can listen for that event and delay, better yet, debounce the execution of your own function by the same duration with an arbitrary allowance.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

var myCustomFunction = debounce(function() {
     console.log("Call this once after resize function completes and only once every 120ms."); 
}, 120);

$(window).on('resize.off-canvas', myCustomFunction );
```

This is based on David Walsh's debounce implementation:

// https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

I haven't really tested it but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to run `myCustomFunction` after the `canvasFunction` finishes. And since `setTimeOut` doesn't return a promise, your functions are not asynchronous (which is what we basically want to do).

To solve this, you can promisify the `setTimeOut` itself, with something like this:

```
`function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
 };`
```

And then call it in your first function as `await timeout(3000)`

Then you can simply make your other function asynchronous as well and them it will execute in the order that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, problem here is i don't have control to edit the first function.

Comment: Oh well. Missed that part, my bad. I don't know how else it can be done. I will delete my answer if it isn't helpful.

Comment: No problem, your solution may be helpful for some other people. Let it be there